# Matlab optimization: what types of objective functions are 'allowed' with fminsearch.m and Co.?

Tags: matlab, optimization

Examples for optimizations with functions like fmincon.m and fminsearchbnd.m usually minimize objective functions that are relatively simple. With simple I mean that the objective function only consists of some algebraic expression, e.g. the Rosenbrock formula.

In my problem, on the other hand, the objective function consists of several steps, including

- computing an L2-norm misfit between an observed data point and a set of n training data points (n~5e4)
- selecting those data points from the training data set that give the lowest misfit
- then using the row indices of this selected subset to compute the final distance that I intend to minimize.

i.e. I perform operations that cannot be formulated as a single mathematical expression. Can I use such an objective function with tools like fminsearchbnd.m or fmincon.m at all? My results so far are not very promising...

Comment: `fminsearch` minimizes any (scalar) function and it does not care how complicated it is. What you need is to have such a function. Whatever you are doing put it in a file, add `function value = myobjfunc(arg1,arg2, ...)` to the top and pass this function to `fminsearch` as `minval = fminseach(@myobjfunc)`.

Comment: Show what you tried that did not work as expected.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone, I think I was not specific enough, I apologise. I have already written a (nested) function that minimises the objective function, and it technically works, i.e. no errors reported. My question was whether there are rules for what an objective function can consist of. From your answers I take that this is not the case. As long as it returns a scalar value it's fine. That's all I needed to know, thanks for your help and sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy and obvious solution for that. You fminsearch() to find a minimum for some self-defined functions. In my example, it is fitting a polynomial, which of course is easy, but the trick is, that this could be anything. You can access the data if you make your objective function as a nested function, so they share the same variable scope.
You can start from the following code and fill in everything you want to do part by part and maybe ask followup questions, if any come up.

```
function main
verbose = 1; % some output

% optimize something, maybe a distorted polynomial
x = sort(rand(20,1));
p_original = [1.5, 3, 2, 1];
y = polyval(p_original,x) + 0.5*(rand(size(x))-0.5);

% optimize polynomial of order order. This is an example of how to pass
% a parameter to the fit function.
order = 3;  

% obvious solution is this, but we want to do something else
p_polyfit = polyfit(x,y,order)

% we want to do it a bit more complex
pfit = optimize_something(x, y, order, verbose)


% what is happening?
figure
plot(x,polyval(p_original,x),'k-')
hold on
plot(x,y,'ko')
plot(x,polyval(p_polyfit,x),'rs-')
plot(x,fit_function(x,pfit),'gx-')
legend('original','noisy','polyfit','optimization')

end



function pfit = optimize_something(x,y, order, verbose)
% for polynomial of order order we need order+1 coefficients
p0 = ones(1,order+1); % initial guess: all coefficients are 1

if verbose
    fprintf('optimize_something calling fminsearch(@objFun)\n');
end

% hand over only p0 to our objective function
pfit = fminsearch(@objFun, p0);

% ------------------------- NESTED objFUN --------------------------------%
function e = objFun(p)
% This function accepts only p as parameter and returns a value e, which
% will be minimized by some metric (maybe least squares).
% Since this function is nested, it can use also the predefined variables x, y (and also p0 and verbose).  
% The magic is, we calculate a value yfitted out of x and p by a
% fit_function. This function can really be anything!

    yfitted = fit_function(x, p);
    e = sum((yfitted-y).^2);
%    e = sum(abs(yfitted-y)); % another possibility     
end
% ------------------------- NESTED objFUN --------------------------------%

if verbose
    disp('pfit found')
end
end


function yfitted = fit_function(x, p)
% In our example we want to fit a polynomial, so we do so. We evaluate the
% polynomial p at x.

    yfitted = polyval(p,x); 

% But it could be anything, really.. each value in p could be something
% else, maybe the sum of an exponential function and a straight line
%     yfitted = p(1)*exp(p(2)*x) + p(3)*x + p(4);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/). It is an addon for Matlab that lets you describe your optimisation problem with normal Matlab code.

*Alternatively*, write down your objective function including any constraints. Your description is not clear to me, and it would help you too, if you would write this down in actual formulae.

I read your steps as this:

1. "Computing an L2-norm between an observed data point and a set of n training data points." It seems that there is a total of one (1) observed data points. Let's call the observed point `x`. Let's call the training data points `y_i` for `i=1..n`.
   The L2-Norm is: `|x-y_i|`.
2. "Selecting those data points [multiple?] that give the lowest misfit". You haven't said how many data points you want, and how you'd combine multiple points to give a single L2-Norm. Let's assume you want exactly one such point (the closest to the observed data point x). Thus you get: `argmin (over i) |x-y_i|`. If you have multiple, you could greedily take the k closest points.
3. "Then using the row indices of this selected subset to compute the final distance that I intend to minimize." And what is the final distance that you intend to minimize?